# page redirection and data not store in database proprely in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

> I am using thymeleaf as frontend technology and springboot as backend.
> I am try to register new user through a registration page but when I
> am  insert data ,data not store in database ,when user data submit and
> press submit button it is not redirect to successPage. it gives me
> this type of error page.
> [image]

> userRegistration.html

```
<form th:action="@{/createNewuser}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>NAME</label> <input type="text" name="name"
                                       th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" />
          </div>
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

> UserEntityController.java

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserEntityController {
    @Autowired
    private UserEntityServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    }
    @GetMapping("/newUser")
    public String saveUser(Model model) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        //model.addAllAttributes("user",user);
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "userRegistration";
    }
    @GetMapping("/successPage")
    public String successPage() {
        return "successPage"; 
    }

    @PostMapping("/createNewuser")
    public String createUawe(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user,
                             BindingResult bindResult,Model model){

        if (bindResult.hasErrors()){
            return "userRegistration";
        }
        if (userServiceImpl.isEmailAlreadyRegistered(user.getEmail())) {
            bindResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "Email is already registered.");
            return "userRegistration";
        }

        if (userServiceImpl.isMobileNoAlreadyRegistered(user.getMobileNo())) {
            bindResult.rejectValue("mobileNo", "error.user", "Mobile number is already registered.");
            return "userRegistration";
        }
         user=userServiceImpl.saveUser(user);
         model.addAttribute("name",user.getName());
        return "redirect:/successPage";
    }



}
```

Comment: Your `UserEntityController` has a base path on it called `/user`. Therefore, you should be accessing `localhost:8080/user/createNewuser`.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using does not match the UserEntityController class.

You are accessing localhost:8080/createNewuser in the browser, which is incorrect.

See your Controller class. At the class level, you have Request Mapping as **/user**.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserEntityController {
```

and then, the method for create user has "createNewuser" mapped with it.

```java
@PostMapping("/createNewuser")
// please correct your method name
public String createUawe(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user,
                             BindingResult bindResult,Model model){
```

Your path should be:

> localhost:8080/user/createNewuser